# Check multiple image size and type in PHP

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $add="../uploads/";
    while(list($key,$value)=each($_FILES['fileUpload']['name']))
    {
        if(!empty($value))
        {
            //old file name
            $filename=$value;
            //give unique name to the file
            $filename=uniqid('img_').''.str_replace(" ","_",$filename);
            copy($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'][$key],$add);
            chmod("$add",0777);
        }
    }
}
```

I have used this code to upload multiple images to the web using the POST method. Can anyone help me check the image size (maximum 1MB each image) and image type like: jpg, png, bmp?

Answer (score 0):

to check the image type use this function :

```
$type = mime_content_type ($value);
```

to get the size in bytes use this function :

```
$size = filesize($value);
```

Comment: OP is looking for the extension of the file, not the mime type though

Comment: Yes, I am searching image extension